# systemd reading variables from file

Tags: shell, debian, systemd

Problem:
My systemd service is not passing flags correctly to golang binary.

I have the following setup:

- Script 1. Extract values from a local file and export variables into a file.

```
if [[ -n "${AGENT_ENV_FILE}" ]]; then
    ENV_FILE_CONTENT=$(cat "${TEMP_ENV_FILE}")
    ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=""
    file_contents=(${ENV_FILE_CONTENT// / })
    for item in "${file_contents[@]}"
    do
      if [[ "${item}" == *"--"* ]]; then
        ADDITIONAL_FLAGS+="${item} "
      fi
    done
    ADDITIONAL_FLAGS="${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS% }"
fi
env | sort > /opt/staging.env
```

- script populates `/opt/staging.env` file with `HEALTH_PATH`, `HEALTH_INTERVAL_SECONDS` and `ADDITIONAL_FLAGS`.
- A systemd service reads from `EnvironmentFile=/opt/staging.env` and extracts values to populate the execution of `/opt/bin/agent`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
StartLimitIntervalSec=600

[Service]
StartLimitBurst=0
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/opt/staging.env
ExecStart=/opt/bin/agent --health-path=${HEALTH_PATH} --health-interval-seconds=${HEALTH_INTERVAL_SECONDS} "${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In my execution I see the correct values:

`ps -ef | grep agent` shows correct values.

```
 /opt/bin/agent--health-path=/health --health-interval-seconds=30 --session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true
```

`/opt/staging.env`

```
ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=--session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true
```

My golang program does not read these variables.
If I manually enter: `--session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true` and remove ${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS} all works fine:

```
ExecStart=/opt/bin/agent --health-path=${HEALTH_PATH} --health-interval-seconds=${HEALTH_INTERVAL_SECONDS} --session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true
```

This works manually:

```
export ADDITIONAL_FLAGS="--session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true"
/opt/bin/agent --health-path=/health --health-interval-seconds=30 ${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}`
```

Only difference I see is that in file I see:

```
ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=--session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true
```

vs manual

```
ADDITIONAL_FLAGS="--session-name=_sess --forward-id=true --rewrite-host=true"
```

Any suggestions?
Not sure why this is happening...?

```
Debian 10
4.19.0-23-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.269-1 (2022-12-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `"${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"` why do you quote it when you need it to be word splitted?

Comment: good hint, I removed the "" and {}, then it worked just $ADDITIONAL_FLAGS